# How can I deactivate user accounts

Tags: sql, wordpress

I've got database with users and i need to deactivate accounts. When user try to login, wordpress should send new activation mail and ask for new password.

How can i make it?

I was try to delete password from database and set user_status to 1, but it's not working :/
Any ideas? (help please)

Comment: You shouldn't need to go into the database to do this. Can't you just use the administrative tools within the Wordpress frontend?

Comment: there is ~2k users:)  However i can set user role or other options, but no activation status :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activation / desactivation is not a native feature of Wordpress.

You can use some plugins like this one : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-approve-user/

After this you disapprove all users and you can make a PHP script which reset all the password and send the new one to the registered mail.

Encoding of the password is in MD5, check this : codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: It's close. I'll try, but admin need to aprove users manualy. In fact the problem is, that users accounts already exist, but i need to reset password for all of them. 

So i don't want to remove accounts and setting, but only exact them to set new password :/

Comment: for that you can install your plugin and reset the approval for all users by using a SQL request. You should try something like this in developpement area.

Comment: that is a way, but still admin need to aprove (or not account), but password is still the same. 

As I said, there is no problem with users, but password can be stolen by proevious people, who worked at this ...

What if If I simple delete passwords and add info "If U already have account, You need to reset password"? But i don't know is it safe. (just thinking)

Comment: you can make a PHP script which reset all the password and send the new one to the registered mail. Encoding of the password is in MD5, check this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: and that is briliant answer :) Propably that is the resolve of my problem :) thanks!

Comment: just found this : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-meta/ which have activation/desactivation option and password reset feature.